# ld.exe: cannot find -llog -lgcc -lc

Tags: rust, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a x86_64-linux-android target on a x86_64-pc-windows-msvc host. Here is my .cargo/config:

```
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
ar = "C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld"
```

When I compile my project with `cargo build --target=x86_64-linux-android --target-dir=./out` (cdylib type), I get this error:

```
 note: C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe: error: cannot find -ldl
          C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe: error: cannot find -llog
          C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lgcc
          C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lc
          C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe: error: cannot find -lm
```

In the directory toolchain's bin directory, I see these possible files:

```
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           973,312 x86_64-linux-android-addr2line.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           998,400 x86_64-linux-android-ar.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         1,745,408 x86_64-linux-android-as.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           902,656 x86_64-linux-android-c++.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           971,264 x86_64-linux-android-c++filt.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           901,632 x86_64-linux-android-cpp.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         2,917,376 x86_64-linux-android-dwp.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM            63,488 x86_64-linux-android-elfedit.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           902,656 x86_64-linux-android-g++.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           899,584 x86_64-linux-android-gcc-4.9.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM            59,904 x86_64-linux-android-gcc-ar.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM            59,392 x86_64-linux-android-gcc-nm.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM            59,392 x86_64-linux-android-gcc-ranlib.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           899,584 x86_64-linux-android-gcc.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           558,080 x86_64-linux-android-gcov-tool.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           529,408 x86_64-linux-android-gcov.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         5,268,992 x86_64-linux-android-gdb-orig.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM            42,496 x86_64-linux-android-gdb.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         1,039,872 x86_64-linux-android-gprof.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         1,793,024 x86_64-linux-android-ld.bfd.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         4,641,792 x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         4,641,792 x86_64-linux-android-ld.gold.exe
12/30/2014  03:14 AM         2,127,360 x86_64-linux-android-ld.mcld.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           983,040 x86_64-linux-android-nm.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         1,140,736 x86_64-linux-android-objcopy.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         2,069,504 x86_64-linux-android-objdump.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           998,400 x86_64-linux-android-ranlib.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           497,152 x86_64-linux-android-readelf.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           973,824 x86_64-linux-android-size.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM           973,824 x86_64-linux-android-strings.exe
03/31/2015  04:13 AM         1,140,736 x86_64-linux-android-strip.exe
```

In a similar StackOverflow post (see: [Failed to cross-compile library from Windows to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189024/failed-to-cross-compile-library-from-windows-to-android)), the linker used is clang, but I can't seem to find it. I'm not sure if I'm even passing a "linker" or not in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change ndk versions, and use the compiled versions inside the llvm toolchain:

```
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
ar = "C:/android-ndk-r21d/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "C:/android-ndk-r21d/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android29-clang.cmd"
```

With a special note, as seen in the aforementioned thread, to use the batch file.

Comment: this didn't work form me, I used cargo ndk instead https://github.com/bbqsrc/cargo-ndk